# Export document-oriented documents to column-oriented structure

Tags: mongodb, export, amazon-dynamodb, export-to-excel, export-to-csv

There are a lot of projects that have an export feature. And sometimes the project has to export the data to column-oriented structure: Excel, CVS Google Spreadsheet, etc.

Once you have a document-oriented document the data from different document could have different structures.

How to export that data to Excel? What's the best approach? To have different pages in the excel for a particular data structure or merge the structure and export it to the one page?

Any ideas are appreciated. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

yes document-oriented schema might be flexible and not abide to a fixed structure however you can still identify the complete possible structure.

eg:

```
doc1 - {name: "alex", age:35, phone:xxx-xxx-xxxx, city:kansas}
doc2 - {name:"stuart:, age:30,phone:yyy-yyy-yyyy, city, newark, state: NJ, sex:M}
```

You can get a complete structure which will be name, age, phone, city, state, sex.

and this will help you map your data to a more structured output for other uses.

i am quite sure even though document-oriented DB gives you flexibility but somebody should not try to fit a car document into a person document just because its flexible and it can store it.